# How do I override text-overflow for a media query in css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, overflow

I have an overflowing paragraph cut to one line when it's below a 768px viewport:

```
.caption p {
    font-size:1.25em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I want to get the full paragraph to show again for a viewport over 768px. **How do I override this for a media query above 768px?**
The text gets all wonky and I can't seem to get the full paragraph by reverting the other properties below. I don't know what to do about text-overflow. I tried "none" but there doesn't seem to be a value for that.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .caption p {
        font-size:1.5em;
        overflow: visible;
        white-space: normal;
        text-overflow: none; /*???*/
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Either place the media query code after the normal css styles for the element, or place `!important` for the `text-overflow`.

#### So either

```
.caption p {
    font-size:1.25em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .caption p {
        font-size:1.5em;
        overflow: visible;
        white-space: normal;
        text-overflow: none;
    }
}
```

#### Or

```
.caption p {
    font-size:1.25em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .caption p {
        font-size:1.5em;
        overflow: visible;
        white-space: normal;
        text-overflow: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The media query doesn't add any specificity, so in a wide window the `<p>` will take whichever properties were assigned last in your CSS. Make sure your special-case media queries are at the bottom.

[The default value for the `text-overflow` property is `clip`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Values)